# Is there a quick way to debug an external meteor package?

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages

You just installed a meteor package, and for some reason it isn't working. You suspect that it's the package itself that has a bug. You want to investigate that. How do you do that?

Optimally, you'd be able to run a command that forks the original package repository with the right version and replaces the original in your meteor application, ready for you to debug it and, once fixed, possibly generate a pull request.

I don't expect something like this to exist as a single command, but is there a workflow that you follow to do exactly that? Or do you approach the problem in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Do a git clone of the package into your local packages folder. Fix any bugs you need to. Commit them. And make a pull request. Once the pull request is accepted, you can remove the local package and use the regular package.

From when I've asked in the past, there isn't really an easier way to do this it seems. But to be honest, this approach isn't too much work.

Also, if you just want to debug, you can step through the package code while it's running without cloning the repo locally. (Assuming it's running in development mode and hasn't been minified by Meteor).

Comment: Thank you!
Breaking news: meteor 1.2 now allows to "Install local plugins from a file path"
https://quip.com/RXFlAk9Rc2xI

Comment: With your approach, do you first "meteor remove" the original? Or does meteor let the local version overwrite the linked package?